# What is the basis for believing Hosea 6:7 is speaking about Adam the man and not men in general?

Tags: kjv, adam, hosea

It is the same word (Adam meaning man) but the KJV translates it as men, any other translations I have checked translate it as 'Adam' himself.

What are the arguments for translating it as 'Adam'?

KJV

> But they like men have transgressed the covenant: there have they
>   dealt treacherously against me.

NASB (for example)

> But like Adam they have transgressed the covenant; There they have dealt treacherously against Me.